# SharePoint workflow History list migration to SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2013, migration, reporting-services, workflow-tasks-list

In our SharePoint 2013 on-premise environment, we have Approval workflows. Using SSRS reports, we display a report, who approved those tasks in a Grid view.

Now we are migrating our complete on-premise environment to SharePoint online, and two things i understood.

1) SharePoint online doesnt have SSRS reports.
2) When migrating content, Workflow history list, being a hidden list, will not be migrated.

I am hoping if there is any way at least to migrate the complete approval task list to SharePoint online list, we can use it a source to build reports from another system list power bi or tableau or is there any better solution?

This is only for existing data for reference purpose, no new records will be added to the workflow history list.

Answer (score 0):

The task list should migrate, depending on what tool you are using.  You can then use PowerBI for reporting.  I'd suggest running a test migration of the task list to see how it will migrate over.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the SharePoint Migration Tool to migrate the complete approval task list from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint online.

You could download the SharePoint migration tool by [the link](https://spmtreleasescus.blob.core.windows.net/betainstall/default.htm).

More reference:

[Using the SharePoint Migration Tool.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/how-to-use-the-sharepoint-migration-tool)

Comment: Can we migrate workflow history list as well?

Comment: No, because the workflow history list is hidden list, we cannot migrate the workflow history list.

Comment: How about exporting that list content to excel and restoring it? Will it have any limitations?

Comment: Yes, you can export the list to excel, but you may encounter the some errors when you import the excel to SharePoint online